# How can I solve an equation with a variable raised to itself?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

example: x^x = 3
I know that I can solve this equation by plotting both of the terms as a function, f(x) = x^x and g(x) = 3, and finding their intersection. But I was wondering whether there was an approach to this equation with an algebraic method or any approach that doesn't involve calculating the intersection of these functions.

Comment: Please try to look around the site and format your question to make it easier to read. You will get more help that way!

Comment: you can use a numerical method,e.g.the Newton Raphson method

Comment: While correct, an answer in terms of the W function doesn't make me feel any smarter.  If I get an answer in terms of trig functions, I know a lot about them to give context.  The W function seems essentially defining the inverse function to $x^x$ and giving it a name.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, that is what the W function does. But there is a reason, namely, that this is the best we can do, since the inverse is not an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).